# "て" in どういたしまして

Tags: grammar, particles, etymology

I have read on other threads here (as well as on other pages online) that the て in expressions such as どういたしまし**て**, 初めまし**て** or あけまし**て**おめでとうございます was not the て-form but rather "a final particle used for a returning remark" (as stated in this thread https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13055/54803), where the person who answered names the particle 反問的用法の終助詞.

Could you please say a bit more on that particle, its etymology, what it means and how it is actually used?

Comment: If you look at Google search results, you can find that all the articles that contain `反問的用法の終助詞` cite [this Wiktionary entry](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6) as the source, and Wiktionary's definition of this て can be found [here](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A6) (軽い疑問・反問を表す).

Answer (score 2):

て in どういたしまして are different from the other two.

[大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A6/#jn-148945) definition only gives the meaning as a question marker: 質問や確かめの気持ちを表す。「あなたにもでき―」「いらしたことあっ―」 (FYI this is normally used by females).

反問的用法 should be a variant of this and interprets どういたしまして as 'What have I done (to be thanked)?'. It is not possible to understand 初めまして or あけまして this way.

---

The other two are more simply te-form, indicating the sentence continues (初めましてよろしくお願いします).

---

Etymology can only be guessed, but all of the above (終助詞 or not) seem to have derived from renyo-kei (stem of te-form) of つ, auxiliary verb for perfective (roughly modern た): [〘接助〙 (完了の助動詞「つ」の連用形から)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A6-573101).

Note all the expressions can be translated with perfect tense: What *have* I *done*?, Now we *have met* for the first time, Now the new year *has come*.