# どういたしまして how should I break it down?

Tags: grammar

I know どういたしまして is translated to "Don't mention it" or "You are welcome" but what is its literal meaning? How should I break it down word by word?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13054/

Comment: @Arfrever Ah, Thank you. So it means (in my feeling) : (why do you thank me that ) I do how(どう）..